# Constructor can not be instantiated

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play, I am using Sorm to persist this `case class` to the database:

```
case class Page(url: String)
```

When I query the database, I get the following object:

```
Stream(Page(1,https://mywebsite.com), ?)
```

I am trying to extract the website name like this:

```
result match {
    case Page(_, website) #:: tail => website
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : models.Page
 required: models.Page with sorm.Persisted
```

What is `sorm.Persisted`?

Why is this error appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query the database you get the stream of *Page with Persisted* mixins. So trying to pattern match on Page causes this error

Try to directly access url like this:

```
result.map {
  page => page.url
}
```

Comment: Then how can I extract the name of the website?